# Open Component from Menu in VueJS 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

OK, so I am NOT a frontend guy. I am trying to get a grasp on things but this one seems to be stumping me. I have a menu (code below) and in there is "VIEW PROFILE" - when someone clicks on it, I want it to open up another vue file I created with a slide out that will contain the users info - the slide out works if I just load it with **`<component name />`** but I am not sure how to set it to be on click. I learn by both just direct me to what terms I need to use or please help me with a solution. Thank you!

To clarify:
I have the menu below in a file we will call index.vue - I also have another file called profile.vue, which is a slide out menu. When someone clicks VIEW PROFILE, I want the slider to come out.

```jsx
<Menu as="div" class="ml-2 flex-shrink-0 relative inline-block text-left">
    <MenuButton class="group relative w-14 h-8 bg-white rounded-full inline-flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
        <span class="sr-only">Open options menu</span>
        <span class="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full rounded-full">
            <DotsVerticalIcon class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500" aria-hidden="true" />
        </span>
    </MenuButton>
    <transition enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-100" enter-from-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95" enter-to-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100" leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-75" leave-from-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100" leave-to-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95">
        <MenuItems class="origin-top-right absolute z-10 top-0 right-9 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
            <div class="py-1">
                <MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
                    <a href="#" :class="[active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm']">View profile</a>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
                    <a href="#" :class="[active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm']">Send whisper</a>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
                    <a href="#" :class="[active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm']">Send mention</a>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
                    <a href="#" :class="[active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm']">Request private chat</a>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
                    <a href="#" :class="[active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm']">Report abuse</a>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
                    <a href="#" :class="[active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm']">Block member</a>
                </MenuItem>
            </div>
        </MenuItems>
    </transition>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Could you provide the relevant .js (or .ts) for this in your question? It would help to help you.

Comment: In this case, there is no <script> What I am trying to understand is what would be a real world example. All I seem to find at MOST is <button> examples but this is just a menu item

Comment: It is a little difficult to grasp the meaning of your question. You mentioned that you are "not the frontend guy". Then it could be a good idea to go with a "batteries included" ui framework like [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com). There is a well documented [menu component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/).

Comment: In that menu - when someone clicks VIEW PROFILE - I want it to open up another vue file... thats it...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an v-if condition to your component

```
    <transition v-if="isOpen" enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-100" enter-from-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95" enter-to-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100" leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-75" leave-from-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100" leave-to-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95">
```

and your MenuButton needs an `@click="isOpen = !isOpen"`

you can provide isOpen from your setup() function if you already use the composition-API otherwise if you use options API just add isOpen to your data().

You can also add an function for this small code Snippet `isOpen = !isOpen`
so you do not have any "real logic" in your HTML which is just something I personally prefer.